# Script to read parameters from file and mkdir and cp accordingly?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, bash, scripting

I have a bunch of files in directories with a file that includes important data like author and title.

```
/data/unorganised_texts/a-long-story
```

Many files in the directories, but most importantly each directory includes `Data.yaml` with contents like this:

```
Category:
  Name: Space
Author: Jôëlle Frankschiff
References:
  Title: Historical
  Title: Future
Title: A “long” story!
```

I need to match these lines as variables $category, $author, $title and make an appropriate structure and copy the directory like so:

```
/data/organised_texts/$category/$author/$title
```

Here is my attempt in bash, but probably going wrong in multiple places and as suggested would be better in python.

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /data/unorganised_texts/*/
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $category ]]; do
    [[ $category =~ “Category:” ]] && echo "$category" && mkdir /data/organised_texts/$category
[[ $author ]]; do
    [[ $author =~ “Author:” ]] && echo "$Author"
    [[ $title ]]; do
        [[ $title =~ “Title:” ]] && echo "$title" && mkdir /data/organised_texts/$category/$title && cp $dir/* /data/organised_texts/$category/$title/
done <"$dir/Data.yaml"
```

Here is my bash version, as I was experimenting with `readarray` and `command eval` and bash version was important:

```
ubuntu:~# bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Thanks!

Comment: does a single `Data.yaml` file contain a single set of `Category/Author/Title` values, or does the file contain multiple such sets? while the subject mentions `mv` there's no indication in the description of what you're trying to `mv` ... can you update the question with more details on what you're trying to `mv`?

Comment: Incidentally whilst there's nothing wrong with doing everything in Bash as an exercise, or for the fun of it, or etc, if you have structured data a language with a built in/readily available yaml parser would be easier.  For instance this would be completely trivial in python.

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks, good points. The mv in title was a mistake, I meant to copy contents of directory to final location. There is plenty of other stuff in the data.yaml including the use of the same labels, but as it is yaml they are indented, so title, author, category only appear once at the root level and that is what I need. Hope that is clear?

Comment: @2e0byo thanks, I don’t know enough python to write it on my own, but happy to receive your example and see about editing it and learning along the way

Comment: @jakethedog I've added a python solution for completeness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It looks you have unmatched do-done pairs.
- The expression `[[ $varname ]]` will cause a syntax error.
- `mkdir -p` can create directories recursively at a time.

Then would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s dotglob                                                # copy dotfiles in the directories as well
for dir in /data/unorganised_texts/*/; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do                                 # read a line of yaml file in "$dir"
        [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]] ]] && continue                 # skip indented (starting with a space) lines
        read -r key val <<< "$line"                             # split on the 1st space into key and val
        val=${val//\//_}                                        # replace slash with underscore, just in case
        if [[ $key = "Category:" ]]; then category="$val"
        elif [[ $key = "Author:" ]]; then author="$val"
        elif [[ $key = "Title:" ]]; then title="$val"
        fi
    done < "$dir/Data.yaml"

    destdir="/data/organised_texts/$category/$author/$title"    # destination directory
    if [[ -d $destdir ]]; then                                  # check the duplication
        echo "$destdir already exists. skipped."
    else
        mkdir -p "$destdir"                                     # create the destination directory
        cp -a -- "$dir"/* "$destdir"                            # copy the contents to the destination
#       echo "/data/organised_texts/$category/$author/$title"   # remove "#" to see the progress
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it does exactly as written on the tin! That said, I had to comment out the line for indentation because the category is part of an YAML indentation. Which leads me to believe this would be better in python which I was trying to cobble together last night. I guess I can ask another question specific to python and reference this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to hear it works so far. You can certainly ask for python answer, which will be more beneficial for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One `bash` idea:

```
unset cat auth title

while read -r label value
do
    case "${label}" in
        "Category:")  cat="${value}" ;;
        "Author:")    auth="${value}" ;;
        "Title:")     title="${value}" ;;
    esac

    if [[ -n "${cat}" && -n "${auth}" && -n "${title}" ]]
    then
        mkdir -p "${cat}/${auth}/${title}"
        # cp ...                                # OP can add the desired `cp` command at this point, or after breaking out of the `while` loop
        break
    fi
done < Data.yaml
```

**NOTE:** assumes none of the values include linefeeds

Results:

```
$ find . -type d
.
./Space
./Space/Jôëlle Frankschiff
./Space/Jôëlle Frankschiff/A “long” story!
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks amazing! What is the correct way to integrate with my for dir in /data/*/ ?

Comment: `mkdir "/data/organised_texts/${cat}/${auth}/${title}"`

Comment: I mean, to have it iterate over all of the directories. like in my attempt? I tried it like this, but I guess it is wrong? ‘for dir in /data/*/‘ and ‘done <“$dir/Data.yaml”

Comment: I can't tell from the description what your overall directory structure is or where the `Data.yaml` files reside; also, your sample code is missing a `do/done` pair (one each for the `for` and `while` loops); having said that, something like: `for dir in /data/unorganised_texts/*; do unset cat auth title; while read -r label value; do see_body_of_while_loop_in_answer; done < "${dir}/Data.yaml"; done`; the `< "$dir/Data.yaml` is fed to the (inner) `while` loop, not the (outer) `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP was interested in a python solution...

First lets make some test dirs:

```bash
pushd /tmp
mkdir t
pushd t
mkdir a-long-story
vim a-long-story/Data.yml # fill in here, or cp.
mkdir irrelevant_dir
mkdir -p irrelevant_dir/subdir
touch notadir
```

Then a simple python script.  Python doesn't (yet) have an ibuilt yaml parser, so `pip install pyyaml` is needed before this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import copytree

from yaml import Loader, load  # pip install pyyaml


def parse_yaml(f: Path) -> dict:
    with f.open() as f:
        return load(f, Loader)


# ROOT = Path("/data/unorganised_texts")
ROOT = Path("/tmp/t")

for subdir in (d for d in ROOT.iterdir() if d.is_dir()):
    yamlf = subdir / "Data.yaml"
    if yamlf.is_file():
        print("Processing", yamlf)
        data = parse_yaml(yamlf)
        other_dirs = ROOT / data["Category"]["Name"] / data["Author"]
        other_dirs.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        outdir = other_dirs / data["Title"]
        if outdir.exists():
            print("skipping as would overwrite.")
        else:
            copytree(subdir, outdir)
```

This code probably doesn't need any explanation even for someone new to python.  But for completeness:

- we import a stdlib class (Path) and fn (copytree)
- we import a 3rd party fn (load) and class (Loader)
- we define a function to parse yaml.  This is probably redundant, but it does add a level of commentary, and lets us easily add more logic here if required later.
- `ROOT.iterdir()` yields up all the dirs at one level in `ROOT`.  We filter these with a generator comprehension to strip out bare files.
- if we find a the yaml we're expecting we make the outdirs, and then if we're not going to overwrite, copy our current directory into the output.

There is nothing remotely wrong with doing this in bash.  These days I'd have written this python version instead, because a. I know python much better than my very rusty bash, and b. it solves the problem 'properly' (e.g. we parse the YAML with a yaml parser), which sometimes makes things more robust.

Note btw that the type hints are optional and ignored at runtime.

Comment: Thanks it does mostly make sense to me. For the category name, it is actually indented in a block like this: `category: name:` that is what I need. how do i get that block data? like this? `data[‘Category:’ : (‘name:’)]`

Comment: @jakethedog oops I didn't notice that.  It just becomes another level in the dictionary (try `print(data)` or better `from pprint import pp` and then `pp(data)` for a prettier output.  So `data["Category"]["Name"]`. I'll update.

Comment: I tested it and it works great. Thanks! The python solution is better in handling UTF characters it seems

Comment: Yeah, python 3 supports utf8 out of the box.  That said I'd use something like `slugify` to generate paths I can type.  Python is great a great toolbox.  Bash is a great swiss army knife ;)

Comment: BTW if you want to have some fun with python, have a look into why `/` (which is normally the division operator) works here to build up paths....